# Cash Drawer Not open via using WebClient Print SDK for EPSON tm-t88V asp .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, printing, epson

The Epson ESC POS Drawer Kick command enables the control of either 1 or 2 Cash drawers

ESC p m t1 t2

we want to open cash drawer using WebClientPrint API
webclientprint.azurewebsites.net

issue:
printer working fine when print text file.
but when we give 0x0A0x1B0x700x000x190xFA0x0A this command to printer
cash drawer not open.

then i use another method ESC/POS to give printer.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
  public void PrintCommands(string useDefaultPrinter, string printerName)
    {

        ClientPrintJob cpj = new ClientPrintJob();
        cpj.BinaryPrinterCommands= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/open.txt"));
        cpj.FormatHexValues = true;
        cpj.ClientPrinter = new DefaultPrinter();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(cpj.GetContent());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting t1 to a larger value (now you have 0x19, which is 25 x 2 msec)?